# How to float table last 2 columns end of the table using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to float last 2 columns like "**output 2**", I can float table like "**output 1**", is it possible to float table 
like "**output 2**".

To get output 1, I calculate column number, then when it comes to 3rd column I add unique id to that columns 
after that I break rows using that id's.

please someone advice me how to display table like "**output 2**".

**Original Code:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1 col 1</td>
        <td>row 1 col 2</td>
        <td>row 1 col 3</td>
        <td>row 1 col 4</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2 col 1</td>
        <td>row 2 col 2</td>
        <td>row 2 col 3</td>
        <td>row 2 col 4</td>       
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>row 3 col 1</td>
        <td>row 3 col 2</td>
        <td>row 3 col 3</td>
        <td>row 3 col 4</td>        
    </tr>    
</table>
```

**Output 1:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1 col 1</td>
        <td>row 1 col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1 col 3</td>
        <td>row 1 col 4</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2 col 1</td>
        <td>row 2 col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2 col 3</td>
        <td>row 2 col 4</td>       
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>row 3 col 1</td>
        <td>row 3 col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 3 col 3</td>
        <td>row 3 col 4</td>        
    </tr>    
</table>
```

**Output 1: jQuery Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('td').each(function(){

              var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
              var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());

              if(col == 2){
                  var newid = "breakId"+row+""+col;
                  $(this).attr('id', newid);
                  var boundary = $("#"+newid);
                  $("<tr>").insertAfter(boundary.parent()).append(boundary.nextAll().andSelf());      
              }
        }); 
</script>
```

**Output 2:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1 col 1</td>
        <td>row 1 col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2 col 1</td>
        <td>row 2 col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 3 col 1</td>
        <td>row 3 col 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>row 1 col 3</td>
        <td>row 1 col 4</td>        
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>row 2 col 3</td>
        <td>row 2 col 4</td>       
    </tr>      
    <tr>
        <td>row 3 col 3</td>
        <td>row 3 col 4</td>        
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').each(function(){             
     var cell3 = $(this).find("td:eq(2)");
     var cell4 = $(this).find("td:eq(3)");
     var newRow = "<tr></tr>";
        newRow= $(newRow).append(cell3);
        newRow= $(newRow).append(cell4);
     $("#table_id").append(newRow);     
 });
```

table_id = Id of your html table

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/calinaadi/xmq4cxj3/)